# Compile error in Eclipse only when passing Object to e.g. Jackson's object mapper

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I experience a strange behavior of Eclipse when applying `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)` to an object `object`.

The class `MyObject` of `object` is in a library which is a direct dependency of my project. The super class `AbstractThing` of `object` is in another library which is a transitive dependency of my project

```
public class MyObject extends AbstractThing {
    //...attributes
}
```

Both libraries are in the build path (using maven)

In a controller I want to convert objects of type `MyObject` to a json String. While creating such objects is not a problem, I get an error in Eclipse if I pass it to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)`:

> The type `AbstractThing` cannot be resolved. It is   indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

Why is that?

Not surprisingly it does not help to add the library containing `AbstractThing` as direct dependency (as the jar is there even without mentioning it explicitly in my `pom.xml`.

The maven build of the project is successful. That's why I guess it is related to Eclipse.

Comment: Could just be that your project is not in sync with the pom file? Have you tried `ctrl+F5` on your project?

Comment: I tried this several times. And as it turns out, it is not related to Jackson, it also happens with Gson. Still: normal usage of `Myobject` is fine, passing it to some other service like Gson or Jackson object mapper, Eclipse complains.